# Java: Fix incorrect timezone in date object

Tags: java, date, timezone

An external API returns an object with a date.
According to their API specification, all dates are always reported in GMT.

However, the generated client classes (which I can't edit) doesn't set the timezone correctly. Instead, it uses the local timezone without converting the date to that timezone.

So, long story short, I have an object with a date that I know to be GMT but it says CET. How can I adjust for this mistake withouth changing my local timezone on the computer or doing something like this:

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(someObject.getDate().toInstant().plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS),
                        ZoneId.of("CET"));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide example values like parseable `String`s? How does the received datetime look? Is it a `String` or is it an instance of `Date` or `LocalDateTime` or even `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: It is already a java.util.date-object (I'm not parsing anything, the provided and generated client-classes do that, falsely, as described).

Comment: So for instance my date object.toString() would return Fri Jan 24 09:15:00 CET 2020 when it actually should be Fri Jan 24 09:15:00 GMT 2020 or  Fri Jan 24 10:15:00 CET 2020

Comment: @ChristophStrehl a `java.util.Date` doesn't have a timezone. It prints in the JVM's default timezone. So, if you're in CET, it will print in CET. "According to their API specification, all dates are always reported in GMT" is simply not possible if they return a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think that is half the truth. The now deprecated `getTimeZoneOffset()` method implies that originally the `java.util.Date` class was designed to also technically contain information about the timezone.

Comment: @Amadán [the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java#l1168) shows that the offset is essentially derived from the JVM's default time zone.

Comment: @AndyTurner The source does not matter. The contract counts. The implementation may change, the contract rarely does.

Comment: @Amadán are you referring to the contract that says "Returns the offset ... for the local time zone relative to UTC"? Yes, that means the JVM's default time zone, as linked in the documentation.

Comment: @ChristophStrehl what does your `Date` print when you invoke its (deprecated) methods `toLocaleString()` and `toGMTString()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr ⇒ use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) for conversion

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // use your date here, this is just "now"
    Date date = new Date();
    // parse it to an object that is aware of the (currently wrong) time zone
    ZonedDateTime wrongZoneZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("CET"));
    // print it to see the result
    System.out.println(wrongZoneZdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));

    // extract the information that should stay (only date and time, NOT zone or offset)
    LocalDateTime ldt = wrongZoneZdt.toLocalDateTime();
    // print it, too
    System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));

    // then take the object without zone information and simply add a zone
    ZonedDateTime correctZoneZdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
    // print the result
    System.out.println(correctZoneZdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-01-24T09:21:37.167+01:00[CET]
2020-01-24T09:21:37.167
2020-01-24T09:21:37.167Z[GMT]
```

---

## Explanation:

The reason why your approach did not just correct the zone but also adjusted the time accordingly (which is good when desired) is your use of a `LocalDateTime` created from an `Instant`. An `Instant` represents a moment in time which could have different representations in different zones but it stays the same moment. If you create a `LocalDateTime` from it and put another zone, the date and time are getting converted to the target zone's. This is not just replacing the zone while keeping the date and time as they are.

If you use a `LocalDateTime` from a `ZonedDateTime`, you extract the date and time representation ignoring the zone, which enables you to add a different zone afterwards and keep the date and time as it was.

Edit: If the code is running in the same JVM as the faulty code, you can use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to get the same time zone as the faulty code is using. And depending on taste you may use `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of `ZoneId.of("GMT")`.

Comment: Thank you, that solution works for me and I also used the adaptions in the comment.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the edit, I would have included it to the answer myself but didn't have time...

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you will not get around some calculations here. I'd strongly suggest to follow an approach based on `java.time` classes, but alternatively you might use the `java.util.Calendar` class and `myCalendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)` for those calculations:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#ZONE_OFFSET